# I don't know how the size of the flow widget in the flutter is determined

Tags: flutter

The size of the image appears different when the flow widget is wrapped in a constrained box versus a stack.

```
Stack(
      children: [
        Flow(
          delegate: TestDelegate(),
          children: [
            Image.network(
              'https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/img-files/effects/parallax/01-mount-rushmore.jpg',
              fit: BoxFit.cover,
            )
          ],
        )
      ],
    )
```

This code will look like this.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/vCT6q.jpg

```
ConstrainedBox(
      constraints: BoxConstraints(maxHeight: 50, maxWidth: 50),
      child: Flow(
        delegate: TestDelegate(),
        children: [
          Image.network(
            'https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/img-files/effects/parallax/01-mount-rushmore.jpg',
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
          )
        ],
      ),
    )
```

And this code will look like this.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ae5T9.jpg

The TestDelegate looks like this.

```
class TestDelegate extends FlowDelegate {
  TestDelegate() : super();

  @override
  void paintChildren(context) {
    context.paintChild(0);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(oldDelegate) {
    return true;
  }
}
```

I don't understand how Flow determines the size of the image it draws.

Please let me know why this is happening.

I tried using SizedBox instead of ConstrainedBox, and Row instead of Stack.
Using Row reduced the size, as did Stack, and SizedBox did nothing.

I want to know why this is happening.

Comment: override this method: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/rendering/FlowDelegate/getSize.html and print incoming `BoxConstraints` in both cases (a constrained box versus a stack), also you can override this: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/rendering/FlowDelegate/getConstraintsForChild.html and print the constraints too

Comment: Try playing with matrix: 
`void paintChild(
int i,
{Matrix4 transform,
double opacity = 1.0}
)` Second argument of paintChild

Comment: @cyberail Thanks, I was able to resize it with your method. Do you also know why there is a difference between using stack and constrainedbox?

Comment: @pskink I'll try it as soon as I get home, thank you.